# http post with flash?

Tags: flash, httpwebrequest

when using http post with flash that send ip address request from client computer or 
server?

Useful Link ( i add it  because when using Google Search with"http post with flash" its first page )

1. http://www.shinedraw.com/data-handling/flash-vs-silverlight-simple-http-post-request/

example

```
var sender = new LoadVars();

sender.x = "xxx";

sender.y = "yyy";

sender.z = "zzz";

sender.send("http://www.yourdomain.com/yourscript.php", "", "post");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what the question is, but I think this is the answer you're looking for: generally speaking, flash is running locally on the client. The connection will therefore be made from the client's system and as a result show the client's IP address.